# lambda expression and Messagebox in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, lambda, messagebox

```
private void SimpleLambda()
{
  dynamic showMessage =  x => MessageBox.Show(x);

  showMessage("Hello World!");
}
```

The Error message is :
Can't convert lambda expression to dynamic type , because it is not a delegate type

Any help,

Comment: Or `Action<string>` or `Func<string, DialogResult>`

Comment: In general, I recommend you treat `dynamic` as an advanced feature to be avoided in normal code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private void SimpleLambda()
{
  Action<string> showMessage =  x => MessageBox.Show(x);

  showMessage("Hello World!");
}
```

Answer (score 16):

This has nothing to do with `MessageBox` - as the error message says, you simply can't convert a lambda expression to `dynamic` as the compiler has no idea what delegate type to create an instance of.

You want:

```
Action<string> action = x => MessageBox.Show(x);
```

Or even use a method group conversion, although then you have to match the return type:

```
Func<string, DialogResult> func = MessageBox.Show;
```

You can *then* use `dynamic` if you want:

```
dynamic showMessage = action; // Or func
showMessage("Hello World!");
```

Alternatively, you can specify the lambda expression in an explicit delegate instance expression:

```
dynamic showMessage = new Action<string>(x => MessageBox.Show(x));
```

Comment: @speti43: As I said in the answer: "the compiler has no idea what delegate type to create an instance of"

Comment: @speti43 Because Show has a return type

Comment: @Mario: Only the method group conversion bit would fail - the lambda expression is fine. If you understood that, it would have been helpful to say so... as well as mentioning the reason to start with :) I've fixed the method group conversion part.

Comment: I see, the problem is when you assign the delegate instance to the dynamic variable.

Comment: @JonSkeet Then you get my +1 then =)

Comment: @speti43: Not quite, it's because the type of the variable is used by the compiler to work out which delegate instance to create in the first place. It's fine to assign a delegate instance to a dynamic variable.

Comment: @Sangram - You should vote based on whether you believe the answer is useful or not, not who wrote it, it is a good answer though.

Comment: @Sayse: of course it was a good answer and deserved a vote. 'JON answered it' was just another fact. Cheers !!

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare the delegate type. Otherwise it won't know what type of lambda expression it's supposed to be—`x` could be anything. This should work:

```
Action<string> showMessage = x => MessageBox.Show(x);
```

See [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) for clarification on what this delegate type is.

Answer (score 1):

I created a type inference helper for this. I don't really like typing out the signature of lambdas if I want to store them in temporary variables so I write

```
var fn = Func.F( (string x) => MessageBox.Show(x) );
```

or

```
var fn = Func.F( (double x, double y) => x + y );
```

You still have to put in the parameter signiture but you let type inference deal with the return type.

Implementation is

```
using System;

namespace System
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Make type inference in C# work harder for you. Normally when
    /// you want to declare an inline function you have to type
    /// 
    ///     Func<double, double, double> fn = (a,b)=>a+b
    /// 
    /// which sux! With the below methods we can write
    /// 
    ///     var fn = Func.F((double a, double b)=>a+b);
    ///
    /// which is a little better. Not as good as F# type
    /// inference as you still have to declare the args
    /// of the function but not the return value which
    /// is sometimes not obvious straight up. Ideally
    /// C# would provide us with a keyword fun used like
    /// 
    ///     fun fn = (double a, double b)=>a+b;
    ///
    /// but till then this snippet will make it easier
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static class Func
    {
        public static Func<A> F<A>(Func<A> f)
        {
            return f; 
        }
        public static Func<A,B> F<A, B>(Func<A, B> f)
        {
            return f; 
        }
        public static Func<A,B,C> F<A, B,C>(Func<A, B,C> f)
        {
            return f; 
        }
        public static Func<A,B,C,D> F<A,B,C,D>(Func<A,B,C,D> f)
        {
            return f; 
        }
        public static Func<A,B,C,D,E> F<A,B,C,D,E>(Func<A,B,C,D,E> f)
        {
            return f; 
        }

        public static Action A(Action f)
        {
            return f; 
        }
        public static Action<_A> A<_A>(Action<_A> f)
        {
            return f; 
        }
        public static Action<_A,B> A<_A, B>(Action<_A, B> f)
        {
            return f; 
        }
        public static Action<_A,B,C> A<_A, B,C>(Action<_A, B,C> f)
        {
            return f; 
        }
        public static Action<_A,B,C,D> A<_A,B,C,D>(Action<_A,B,C,D> f)
        {
            return f; 
        }
        public static Action<_A,B,C,D,E> A<_A,B,C,D,E>(Action<_A,B,C,D,E> f)
        {
            return f; 
        }
    }

}
```